# Copying one object to another Object is yielding different results in java

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer a = 1;
    Integer b = 0;
    b=a;
    System.out.println(a);
    System.out.println(b);
    ++a;
    System.out.println(a);
    System.out.println(b);
}
```

output : 1
1
2
1

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> b = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    a.add(1);
    a.add(1);
    a.add(1);
    a.add(1);
    b=a;
    System.out.println(a.size());
    System.out.println(b.size());
    b.add(2);
    System.out.println(a.size());
    System.out.println(b.size());
}
```

output : 4 
4 
5 
5

For above code why both objects are not referring to same memory location.

Comment: They are. The size of the ArrayList increases by 1 when you add the number 2 to the list

Comment: `++a` doesn't change the contents of the object `a` refers to; it makes `a` refer to a new object different from `b`.

Comment: The keywords here are, mutable and immutable. The primitive type(Integer) you used in the first code block is immutable which means it's state cannot be changed after creation. The ArrayList on the other hand is mutable so it's state can be modified after creation. Go have a look at this link http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/immutable.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Case -1 :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer a = 1;
    Integer b = 0;
    b=a;                      // 2 references a and b point to same Integer object
    System.out.println(a);
    System.out.println(b);
    ++a;                      // now a references to a new integer object with value 2 where as b refers to old integer object with value 1
    System.out.println(a);
    System.out.println(b);
}
```

Case 2 :

Again both `a` and `b` both refer and work on *same* arrayList instance. So modifying using one reference is reflected in other reference as well

Comment: instead of Integer i am using int, i am getting the same result as explained above... can you please let me know why it is behaving so??

Comment: @Abhishek - Where case 1  or case 2?

Comment: @Abhishek - because again a will be 2 and b will be 1. You could try the same thing with `StringBuilder` and try changin it. Sonce StringBuilder is *Mutable*, you will see that the values changed by one reference will be reflected in another.

Answer (score 3):

This is because Integer are immutable. Once created, you can't change it. If you wants to force the value to change, it will point to a new memory location. When you did `++a`, `a` becomes a new object.

---

It might be easier  if you look at it from the point of view of a String. (String are immutable as well)

```
    String s1 = "aaa";
    String s2 = s1;

    s1 = "bbb";
    System.out.println("s1: " + s1);
    System.out.println("s2: " + s2);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
s1: bbb
s2: aaa
```

Answer (score 3):

All the wrapper classes are immutable in Java actually. We know String as a famous immutable class. In addition to it other wrappers like Integer is also immutable.

See this http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077343/learn-java/java-s-primitive-wrappers-are-written-in-stone.html

Answer (score 2):

```
    Integer a = 1;
    Integer b = 0;
    b=a;
    System.out.println(a);
    System.out.println(b);
    if(a == b){
        System.out.println("Both objects are equal");
    }
    ++a;
    if(a != b){
        System.out.println("Both objects are different");
    }
    System.out.println(a);
    System.out.println(b);
```

Answer (score 0):

`++a` creates a new object `=a+1` then sets `a =` this new object. `b` is not changed because assignment doesn't affect the object that was contained in the variable being reassigned.

On the other hand `.add(2)` adds `2` to the list specified by `a`, which is the same reference as the one specified by `b` since they have been equated.